# I upgraded a Cisco switch to a newer model with different SNMP OIDs. Can I have the new switch receive the old OID and report values from the new OID?

Tags: cisco, switch, snmp

I upgraded from a Cisco SG300-10MP to a Cisco SG350-10MP. A piece of software is looking for the value from 1.3.6.1.2.2.1.8.50, but the OID on the new switch is 1.3.6.1.2.2.1.8.2. The final number refers to the Ethernet port on the switch. I can either configure something on the switch or I can rewrite the software that sends SNMP queries. I’ve heard about applets that can run on switches, but I’m not sure how to start. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I have the new switch receive the old OID and report values from
> the new OID?

No. The MIB for a device defines the OIDs, and it seems the MIB for your new switch has different OIDs for some things.

> I’ve heard about applets that can run on switches, but I’m not sure
> how to start. What should I do?

The Cisco small business devices do not run IOS, so they do not run EEM scripts. Also, you could not intercept an SNMP query with an EEM script.

Comment: I read a moment ago that the OID suffix here which points to the Ethernet port is indexed by ifIndex. I’ve searched for ifIndex configuration, but I’ve only seen resources that share how to enable ifIndex persistence. Do you know if there is a way to configure custom ifIndex numbers?

Comment: *ifIndex* is read only, you can't change them (via SNMP or elsewhere).